# NGX-MASK error after upgrade from Angular 6 to 7

Tags: angular

After upgrading my project from Angular 6 to 7, the NGX-MASK module broke. I have some mask like '99999-999', after upgrade when I type in the field they stopped type when found the first special character like '12343-'. Before upgrading its work like '12345-123'. If I remove the special character it´s work.

I have been fixed some version of angular and upgrade the ngx-mask to tried solve this.

https://github.com/wantero/ngx-mask-error

Answer (score 1):

Changed the format from '99999-999' to '00000-000' and it's work!